# SVG Sprites in WordPress: What's the best way to implement SVG sprites?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, svg

I have a question about implementing SVG sprites in WordPress. I've done a whole lot of research on this, and the best way to create and add svg sprites from using AJAX, to including the svg sheet in the php template. 
I'm more of a technical SEO guy than a front-end dev, so I'm confused by one thing: 
If I include the svg sprites file in the head or body in php, will that create bloat on pages?
I have more than 150 svg icons, and the svg sprites file is more than 500kb, I'm afraid that if I include the file in php, then for every page of the website, the client has to request and download this file, which would slow down the website.

Not sure if this correct or not, could you help me out and let me know if the client needs to download this 500kb on every page load if I include it in the php template?
If that's true, what's the best way to implement SVG sprites in WordPress without bloating up pages and slowing down the page speed?